# Java OOP transient field initialising upon loading POJO parent

Tags: java, class, oop, syntax, initialization

So I have a very large class with hundreds of transient Objects which need to be re-initialized every time the parent (In this case Person.class) is LOADED. (the Peron.class is loaded and saved)

Here is an example of how my class structure is at the moment:

```
public final class Person {

    private transient ObjectA a;
    private transient ObjectB b;
    private transient ObjectC c;
    private transient ObjectD d;
    //and hundreds more...

    public Person() {

        initTransientObjects();

    }

    private void initTransientObjects() {

        a = new ObjectA();
        b = new ObjectB();
        c = new ObjectC();
        d = new ObjectD();
        //and hundreds more...
    } 

    public void onReloadAfterFirstSave() {
        initTransientObjects();
    }

}
```

This is making writing new objects very tedious and I'm wondering if there is a way that I can do it more compact like this:

```
public final class Person {

    private transient ObjectA a = new ObjectA();
    private transient ObjectB b = new ObjectB();
    private transient ObjectC c = new ObjectC();
    private transient ObjectD d = new ObjectD();
    //and hundreds more...
    //this way I only have to type the new object once instead of twice

    public void onReloadAfterFirstSave() {
        //what here? because now transient fields are null
    }

}
```

Note that the reason I cannot use the above is that, obviously when Person is loaded again the transient fields will not be loaded and therefore automatically be set to null.

What should I do here?

Edit:

There are also non transient objects I am saving in the Person class as well as these transient fields which is why using this is not an option:

```
Peron person = new Person(); //every load
```

Comment: This seems really weird ... are you writing the object to disk? Why are you referencing so many different types in you Person class?

Comment: It is being saved as an Object, but think of it as a real person, who would have lots of properties, like a tv, car, house, etc...

Comment: If you serialise the person but not its data - it still das not make any sense. You need a different kind of abstraction. Without knowing what you are building, your code is hard to refactor.

Comment: not to mention all your objects will lose its state after every "reloadafterfirstsave", at which point it is no different from just doing "person = new Person()" (unless you have non-transient properties that you did not mention)

Comment: I do serialize some of the Person's data (which is not transient; which is not shown here because it is not the issue at matter), but the person will have certain things which need to be reset every load, for example, car and house would not be transient and would be saved, however, an object like TodaysTVProgramSchedule.class will change (assuming player is reloaded every day)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, but I don't condone doing it, mostly because you will need to be very careful with the exceptions.
I will assume that your constructors for ObjectA, ObjectB, ObjectC aren't empty, and if they are then this will be easier to implement.

I made an example class just for you

```
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.util.Random;

/**
 *
 * @author emngaiden
 */
public class Test2 {

    ClassContainer[] containers;
    Object[] instantieted_objects;

    public Test2() {
        initObjects();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test2 test=new Test2();
        StringBuilder sb=(StringBuilder)test.getObject(2);
        sb.append((String)test.getObject(0));
        sb.append(((Random)test.getObject(1)).nextDouble());
        System.out.println(sb.toString());
    }

    public Object getObject(int i){
        return this.instantieted_objects[i];
    }

    private void initObjects() {
        //total number of objects ObjectA, ObjectB etc...
        int number_of_objects = 3;
        this.containers = new ClassContainer[number_of_objects];
        this.instantieted_objects = new Object[number_of_objects];
        //create the containers, you write this only one, and can
        //share it between objects of the same class
        this.containers[0] = new ClassContainer(String.class,
                new Class[]{String.class},
                new Object[]{"hello world"}
        );
        this.containers[1] = new ClassContainer(Random.class,
                new Class[]{long.class},
                new Object[]{192323l}
        );
        this.containers[2] = new ClassContainer(StringBuilder.class,
                null,
                null
        );
        //poblate the objects in the array
        for(int i=0; i<this.containers.length; i++){
            try{
                this.instantieted_objects[i]=instantiateObject(containers[i]);
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    //returns a new object instance based on the container
    private Object instantiateObject(ClassContainer container)
    throws NoSuchMethodException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException,
    IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException {
        //no arguments for the constructor means that the constructor is empty
        if(container.args!=null){
            //get the constructor that matches the Class[] array on its arguments
            return 
                container.obj.getConstructor(container.args)
                .newInstance(container.values);
        }
        else{
            return container.obj.newInstance();
        }
    }

    //class to hold the necessary data to instantiate the object
    public class ClassContainer {

        //the target class, for ObjectA(int,int)this must be ObjectA.class 
        Class obj;
        //the argument classes, it would be {int.class,int.class}
        Class[] args;
        //the actual values for the constructor, it would be {1,2}
        Object[] values;

        public ClassContainer(Class obj, Class[] args, Object[] values) {
            this.obj = obj;
            this.args = args;
            this.values = values;
        }
    }
}
```

This was fun to code, but I wouldn't recommend using it.

Comment: interesting. I've done this before on other projects and found creating the getters and setters with the extra casting required (Which cannot be done automatically with an ide) was just as tedious as the just oop type method I'm using. But I'd like to hear other peoples opinion on this as well